# How to avoid iterating over dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a dataframe `df` with columns 'Name', 'Date' and 'Id'. The 'Id' column is initially all 0 and I want to populate it as follows: the rows that have the same 'Date' and `same_names(name_i, name_j) == True` take the same Id.

I managed to do it with a for-loop which goes over the rows of the df:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

def same_names(name1, name2):
    name1_parts = name1.split()
    name2_parts = name2.split()
    # Compare last names
    return name1_parts[-1] == name2_parts[-1]

# Sample data
data = [
    ['John Smith', '2022-01-01', 0],
    ['Mary Johnson', '2022-01-04', 0],
    ['Mark Williams', '2022-01-02', 0],
    ['Jessica Brown', '2022-01-03', 0],
    ['David Lee', '2022-01-03', 0],
    ['John Brown', '2022-01-02', 0],
    ['Frank Johnson', '2022-01-04', 0],
    ['Mary Lee', '2022-01-03', 0],
    ['David Lee', '2022-01-03', 0]
]

header = ['Name', 'Date', 'Id']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)


date_to_index = defaultdict(list)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    date = row['Date']
    if date in date_to_index:
        for i in date_to_index[date]:
            prev_row = df.iloc[i]
            if same_names(prev_row['Name'], row['Name']):
                df.at[index, 'Id'] = prev_row['Id']
            else:
                df.at[index, 'Id'] = df["Id"].max() + 1
                date_to_index[date].append(index)
    else:
        if index > 0:
            df.at[index, 'Id'] = df["Id"].max() + 1
        date_to_index[date].append(index)

df.sort_values(by="Id", inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
            Name        Date  Id
0     John Smith  2022-01-01   0
1   Mary Johnson  2022-01-04   1
2  Frank Johnson  2022-01-04   1
3  Mark Williams  2022-01-02   2
4  Jessica Brown  2022-01-03   3
5      David Lee  2022-01-03   4
6       Mary Lee  2022-01-03   4
7      David Lee  2022-01-03   4
8     John Brown  2022-01-02   5
```

Is there a way to vectorize this code (or make it faster in any other way)? Maybe using `groupby` somehow, but the problem is that I compare the names using a function `same_names` and not just by equality, which complicates it.

**Note**: the `same_names()` function may be different from the example because in reality the names can be more messy (e.g. instead of 'Mary Johnson' it can be 'Johnson Mary' or 'Ms Mary Johnson', so I still have to figure out what `same_names()` will be).

Comment: Can you add a sample data set?

Answer (score 1):

You can split the column and get last element in list then use [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) to encode the Series value as an enumerated type

```py
df['Id'] = pd.factorize(df['Name'].str.split(' ').str[-1])[0]
```

```
print(df)

            Name        Date  Id
0     John Smith  2022-01-01   0
1   Mary Johnson  2022-01-04   1
2  Mark Williams  2022-01-02   2
3  Jessica Brown  2022-01-03   3
4      David Lee  2022-01-03   4
5     John Brown  2022-01-02   3
6  Frank Johnson  2022-01-04   1
7       Mary Lee  2022-01-03   4
8      David Lee  2022-01-03   4
```

Comment: Didn't know about `pd.factorize`, so thanks for this. However, the real situation may be different, e.g. instead of "Mary Johnson" it can be "Johnson Mary", or "Ms Mary Johnson"  , so that's why I need to use the function `same_names()` which will be different from the example. Sorry for not clarifying this.

Comment: @orbit If so, I think there is no silver bullet for your situation. And you'd better include these outliers in your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I get that your function `same_names` might be different.

Still, if it is always a comparison, you can use a function (`identity` below) to compute a temporary column used to group by. This is the same mechanism as the `key` argument of the standard [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#sorted) function.

You'll also need a counter from `itertools` to generate ids.

And you can drop the `"Id"` column in the first place if you don't use it.

Here is how to do it:

```py
>>> from itertools import count
>>> counter = count(0)

>>> def identity(s):
...     return s.split()[-1]

>>> df.assign(
...     identity=df["Name"].apply(identity),
... ).groupby(
...     by=["identity", "Date"], group_keys=False
... ).apply(
...     lambda x: x.assign(Id=next(counter)),
... ).drop(
...     columns=["identity"],
... ).sort_values(
...     by="Id", ignore_index=True
... )

            Name        Date  Id
0     John Brown  2022-01-02   0
1  Jessica Brown  2022-01-03   1
2   Mary Johnson  2022-01-04   2
3  Frank Johnson  2022-01-04   2
4      David Lee  2022-01-03   3
5       Mary Lee  2022-01-03   3
6      David Lee  2022-01-03   3
7     John Smith  2022-01-01   4
8  Mark Williams  2022-01-02   5
```